# OracleConnection.ClearAllPools - Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracleclient

I have the following code in an ashx file - don't ask why  ;-)

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="Site.Pool" %>

using System;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.SessionState;

using Core.Database;
using Core.ITables;
using Online.Server.Busi;
using Online.Server.ITables;
using XactNet.Busi;

namespace Site
{
    public class Pool : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState
    {
            public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
            {
            try
            {
                Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.ClearAllPools();
                context.Response.Write("SUCCESS");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                context.Response.Write(e.ToString());
            }

        }

            public bool IsReusable
            {
                get { return false; }
        }
        }
}
```

When called, the exception gets written out:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object. 
at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.ClearAllPools() 
at Site.Pool.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
```

Any suggestions as to what state the connection pools need to be in before trying to clear them?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the default error message for InvalidOperationException, so don't assume it has any significant meaning in this case... apparently Oracle didn't bother to write an explicit error message.

Here's the code of the ClearAllPools method, according to Reflector :

```
public static void ClearAllPools()
{
    if (!OracleInit.bSetDllDirectoryInvoked)
    {
        OracleInit.Initialize();
    }
    if (((ConnectionDispenser.m_ConnectionPools == null) || (ConnectionDispenser.m_ConnectionPools.Count == 0)) && ((ConnectionDispenser.m_htSvcToRLB == null) || (ConnectionDispenser.m_htSvcToRLB.Count == 0)))
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }
    ConnectionDispenser.ClearAllPools();
}
```

So apparently it throws this exception when there is no connection pool, and I see no way of checking that... so eventually the only option is to catch the exception

Comment: Yeah, I opened it up in reflector as well and saw the same.  No idea why I didn't have a connection pool at the time (maybe the app restarted when I put the ashx file out there...)