# Oracle ODP.net: recognizing modified tnsnames.ora without restart

Tags: c#, oracle, ado.net, odp.net

So here's our situation: We have some software that needs to do some db configuration. Could be SQL, could be Oracle, etc. If it's Oracle, we do a test connection and if we get a 12154 (TNS: couldn't resolve) we prompt the user for a new copy of the tnsnames.ora, which we put in the appropriate place. Now, if we stop the program and restart it the test will now work fine, which is good, but we'd really like to do is to be able to rerun the test without restarting the program.

So far, I've tried changing the connection string to add "pooling='false'", and also doing OracleConnection.ClearAllPools() before and after each connection test, but no dice.

Due to the fact that we accept multiple db providers, our test basically starts with a DBConnection object and then uses a dbProviderFactory to return the appropriate connection to it. Then we just assign the ConnectionString and attempt to Open:

```
DbConnection conn = null;

DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(provider);

conn = factory.CreateConnection();
OracleConnection.ClearAllPools();
conn.ConnectionString = connectionString;
conn.Open();
```

So that's basically it. If anyone can tell me how to clear that connection out so that it recognizes the new tnsnames.ora file and connects correctly, I will be very grateful. Thanks.

Comment: What version of Oracle Client are you using.. there is an easier way to accomplish this if you are using .config file along with a similar connection string setup in the .config file.. I am currently using Oracle 11.x.x and Oracle 12.x.x along with the Oracle 32bit client installed and it eliminates the need / use of TNS Names file..

Comment: Hi. Our clients are using 11 & 12 per our requirements, and 64 bit. I should probably explain this is installation software for our product so we don't know what database they're going to use as long as it's one of the ones we support, so I'm not sure if the config file would really be a usable solution.

Comment: I am not sure in your case but I am using the same platform and was able to find a work around using tns names.. I think that depending on how your installation is configured this can be done with some minor tweaks but I can't tell being that I do not know your process.. how are you configuring the current installation currently.. also are you using an up to date master tns names file that one individual maintains prior to pushing the updates for the installation...?

Comment: Not sure if I understand quite what you're asking here. The tns file is provided by the user and is presumably configured to whatever oracle setup they've got. We make sure (if they select Oracle as a db option) that they do in fact have it installed, and do the connection test at the appropriate place (i.e., when they define the connection parameters). I'm not sure what else you need. This is my first time dealing with Oracle anything, actually.

Comment: I totally understand being that I normally deal with Sql Server.. the theory is pretty much the same.. I guess I am at a loss because as long as their TNS Names is setup correctly then I don't see why this would be an issue.. unless they are not restarting the application.. then I can see where this can be an issue in regards to a current Instance vs a new Instance.. so in order to fix it.. I would suggest having some sort of flag that checks or gets set if the new tnsNames was used..then invoke a call to the same initialization code that's used on initial startup..does that make sense

Comment: Well, this isn't out the door yet; we've got a test system that represents the end user doing a fresh install and all that. As I said, when they restart the install (after copying the 'good' tns file), it works hunky dory. We just want to find a way to not make them have to do that. I've already got it clearing out and creating new instances of the connection objects and all that associated with the connection test, and of course the pools are being flushed, so I'm kind of at a lost. We just need to goose it and say hey, the tns has been changed :/

Comment: you need a way of notifying the installation app that the file has changed so this is the part you need to implement and when it's changed then call the same method(s) that are used when start up is normal.. seeing how you initialize if that's the code that you have posted..then you need to call the `Factory Method` again it doesn't sound that trivial..can you show the full method signature for that code block above..

Comment: Well, see, that's what we're doing. We prompt for the new file, copy it over to the new place, then when they hit the test button again, everything is initialized fresh--including the factory method--but nevertheless the new file doesn't "take".

Comment: can you personally test this to verify and validate vs letting some other system or process down stream do the assumptions for you.. I wonder if the file that's being read from has not been fully closed or where in the process is the file being flushed to insure its contents have been fully written/ updated before assuming that all has worked out properly..

Comment: check this posting out as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289057/oracleconnection-clearallpools-operation-is-not-valid-due-to-the-current-state
other than that I am wondering if it's holding on to the old connection which could explain the issue you are seeing

Comment: also I read an article that states that you should not call the following until a valid connection has been established with the database then you should call `OracleConnection.ClearAllPools();`

Comment: I'm looking into this answer for you, but did you know about SQLNET EZ Config? It takes host, port and service name and can avoid the need to have them provide you an entire tnsnames.ora. If EZ Connect is not configured to work, you can also construct a TNS alias as if it were in the TNSNAMES.ORA and feed that right into connect string.. eg Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=MyHost)  (PORT=MyPort)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=MyOracleSID)));User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;

Comment: EZ Connect example: Data Source=myserver:1521/my.service.com;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword; Using either technique you can simply create a Oracle connect dialog rather than asking them to provide a tnsnames.ora